# SSIS Variables and Parameters written to wrong Access Fields

Tags: sql, visual-studio, ms-access, ssis

I'm using a Control Flow and Data Flow tasks to record the number of rows read from an Excel data source in Visual Studio SSIS. The data is then processed into good and bad tables, the rows in these counted and the results written into a statistics table via a parameterised SQL statement.

For reasons unknown the data seems to be getting written into the wrong fields in the statistics table and despite recreating the variables and explicitly setting the columns for each variable I can't fix or identify the problem.

Three variables are set:
1. Total rows read from source Excel via a Row Count task (approx 28964 rows)

2. Rows written to table as 'good' data after processing (most of the source files, approx 28,540)
3. Rows written to table as 'bad' data after processing (approx 424)

Then the varables are stored in a separate table via a SQL command that reads parameters set from the variables. A final percentage field is calculated from the total rows and the errors.

However, the results in the table seem to be in the wrong fields (see image).

I've checked this several times and recreated all the tables and variables but get the same result. All tables are Access.

Any ideas?

Any help is much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that an Access parameterised query?

I've never run one of those from SSIS.  I do know that SSIS can be weird about mapping the values from the variables to the query parameters.  Have you noticed that the display order of your variables (in the variable-to-parameter mapping) is the same as how they get assigned to parameters?

It looks as though the GoodRows value (28540) is going to P1, BadRows to P2 and TotalRows to P3.  That's the order that the variables appear in the mapping.

This is exactly the bizarre, infuriating thing that I've seen SSIS do - though not specifically with Access SQL statements.  SSIS sometimes maps your variables to the parameters *in the order that they appear in the mapping list, completely ignoring what you specify in the Parameter Name column*.

Try deleting all the mappings, and mapping the variables one after another so that they appear in the order P1, P2, P3 in the mapping table.

Comment: Yes that was it, bizarre. Many thanks for you excellent help. What a weird quirk for a professional program.

Comment: Glad that fixed it!  I think SSIS blames the data providers for this behaviour.  I seem to remember that it happens with one flavour of SQL Server connection (perhaps OLEDB), but not with another (SQL Server), though I can't remember the details.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you create a fourth variable for the fourth parameter rather than trying to do math in the ExecuteSQL task.

Instead of using P1, P2 & P3 in the Parameter Names column of the Parameter-mapping tab, try using their zero-based ordinal position.

In the query itself, use question marks for the parameters:

```
...VALUES ("France", ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

In other words, for the parameter used first in the query, use 0 for the name.   Use 1 for the next parameter, 2 for the next parameter, and so on.

If that doesn't work, you can use your variables to build a string variable that holds the entire SQL string that you want to execute, and use the "SQL from Variable" option in the ExecuteSQL task.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to replace the Parameter Names in the Parameter Mapping with 0, 1 and 2. 
Just use numbers in the column order you need. In my SSIS-Projects this works fine.

Comment: Thanks, yes it was mapping to the order that the params were defined rather than the SQL code.